# Understanding/analyzing a power supply circuit

Tags: capacitor, diodes, rectifier

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLO5N7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I'm having some problems with this exercise, it is given:

$$V_1=220V_{rms}/60Hz\\\frac{V_2}{V_1}=1/15\\C=0,5mF\\R_L=12V \text{ and }1200mW\\\text{Led: }I_F=15mA \text{ for }V_F=2V\\\text{Voltage Regulator: For }15V<V_i<27V \rightarrow V_0=12V$$

It askes for the graph of \$V_i(t)\$, the resistance \$R_{Led}\$ and the voltage amplitude in the capacitor. The diodes are ideal (0V drop) and despise the regulator consumption.

Now I'm having problems with the following:

1) What is the meaning of the two expression: \$R_L=12V\$ and \$1200mW\$, \$\text{Led: }I_F=15mA \text{ for }V_F=2V\$? For the resistor is it the power when the voltage is 12V? For I is it the current when \$V_f=2V\$? If it is it doesn't make much sense since \$V_0=12V\$ always. Could I just multiply by 6 to get current for 12V?

2) It seems that I have to calculate the voltage on the capacitor? If so (and even if don't), I know the formula for the voltage according to time \${\displaystyle V(t)=V_{0}(1-e^{-t/\tau })}\$ (charging) but I've only applied to circuits with one resistance, how to do it in the circuit above? I imagine that would something more complex than calculating the equivalent resistance in parallel or series.

Excuse me my english and I appreciate any help I can get.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your exercise is awkwardly worded...
The LED specification seems clear enough: your are required to choose **Rled** so that 15 mA. will flow through **LED** and **Rled**. With 15 mA. flowing through **LED**, you are told that the voltage drop across LED terminals is 2.0 volts.
The specification for **RL** makes no sense: "RL=12V" ?? Am suspecting that you must choose the ohmic value of RL so that it dissipates 1200mW when 12v appears across its terminals.
I would also assume that input voltage **V1** is a 220v rms **sinusoidal waveform.** It is clear that its frequency is 60 Hz. and you should assume that the transformer is lossless, stepping down voltage by a factor of 15. The 7812 voltage regulator is simplified as well to a lossless component, consuming no current of its own - generating exactly 12v DC at its output terminal, provided input voltage is above 15v and below 27v. Whatever current flows into its input terminal emerges from its output terminal.
Be aware that since the regulator provides a *constant output voltage*, then *current will be constant too*, regardless of an input voltage that varies. This means that your exponential equation doesn't apply here. Think carefully about this before proceeding to solve for voltage across **C**.